# Explain the o/p of echo $_

Tags: bash, shell

When I do

```
$ du
$ echo $_
```

I get o/p as du. Why is that ?

About - man bash says: "At  shell  startup,  set  to  the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list. **Subsequently, expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion.**  Also set to the full pathname used to invoke each  command  executed and placed in the environment exported to that command.  When checking mail, this parameter holds the name of the mail file currently being checked."

So $_ should be empty, there is no argument to du in the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument is always the name of the executed program or script.

In this case last = first.

"...the name by which the program was called..."

[Link](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html)